# T-SQL query optimize

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, correlated-subquery

I have a query with very poor performance. In the production database, there are tens of millions rows of data.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN tab1.col1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
     FROM tab1 
     WHERE tab1.col2 = tab2.col2
       AND (tab2.col1 <> 1
            OR (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab1 AS p1 WHERE tab1.col4 = p1.col4) = 0)
       AND (tab1.col3 = 1 OR tab2.col1 = 0
            AND ISNULL((SELECT SUM(tab3.col1) FROM tab3 WHERE tab3.col1 = tab2.col2), 0) < tab1.col5)) col_alias
FROM 
    tab2
```

I have already tried to resolve performance problem with indexes, JOINs and CTE. But since there is usage of aggregate functions and correlated subqueries, I have not dome anything which improve the performance.

Does anybody have any ideas how I can do improve this?

Query plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJSUd1pOX

[image]

Comment: Attach a query plan?

Comment: Generate the query plan, then paste the XML version at https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and share the link here. This will help analyze how to improve the query.

Comment: This is quite a complicated query. I suppose with all those lookups and `OR` conditions, there is not much you can do to get this faster. Of course there should be indexes on `tab1(col2)`, `tab1(col4)`, and `tab3(col1)`. You may get this a tad faster by replacing the index on `tab1(col2)` with a covering index on `tab1(col2,col3,col4,col5,col1)`.

Comment: Could you explain what the query is supposed to be doing?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Keep in mind that  p or q and r  is interpreted as   p or (q and r)

Answer (score 2):

Without a query plan, and since all your column names are generic, and I'm not sure what it is you're trying to produce, I can't tell you things which are or aren't necessary to have in there. But here's some general advice:

Your affinity for correlated subqueries is probably not helping things, nor is the fact that your predicates `OR`'d together. It's quite likely that your procedure is sometimes or always doing a full table scan since it doesn't know what kind of inputs you're likely to have.

First I'd recommend breaking out the different `OR`'d cases into their own if/else branch. That way each statement can get a query plan scoped to what *it* is doing.

I'd also see if you can do this in several steps. Maybe get a nice efficient seek against your big table and plop that in a temp table or something, and then operate on the much smaller, isolated set.

Answer (score 0):

This of course will not compile, however, if the Colxxx fields are properly indexed then you possibly can gain speed by aggregating on sums and flags and performing some of the conditionals there as opposed to row by row.

```
SELECT
    MinFlag = MIN(MinFlag)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        Table1Column2 = tab1.Col2,
        MinFlag = CASE WHEN tab1.col1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
        SumTable3Column1= tab3.col1 ,
        ConditionThreeFlag = CASE WHEN tab1.col3 = 1 OR tab2.col1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        Tabel1Column5 = tab1.col5
    FROM 
        tab2
        INNER JOIN tab1 ON tab1.col2 = tab2.col2 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tab3 ON tab3.col1 = tab2.col2
    WHERE 
        (tab2.col1 <> 1 OR tab1.col4 IS NULL)

)AS X
GROUP BY
        X.Table1Column2 
HAVING 
    ((MAX(ConditionThreeFlag) = 1) AND (SUM(SumTable3Column1) < MAX(Tabel1Column5)))
```

**EDIT :** I am lost here, I thought about it a bit and decided that this will always be false (count of all col4 joined again on col4 where count==0) or are you saying where col4 = count of all records in tab1??

Comment: I agree that the statement "(select count(*) FROM tbl1 AS p1 WHERE tab1.col4 = p1.col4) = 0" must always evaluate to false.  There will always be at least one record.

Comment: (select count...=0    will be true if col4 is null

Comment: In a nutshell, the statement, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab1 AS p1 WHERE tab1.col4 = p1.col4) = 0)  is like an inverse way of specifying ( OR tab1.col4 IS NULL)

Comment: So we conclude that (select count...=0 can be replaced with "tab1.col4 is null"?

Comment: Sorry for the earlier comment.  That should've been  "IS NULL".